# How to draw a triangle with OCaml and GLFW?

Tags: opengl, ocaml, glfw

I tried to draw a triangle with OCaml using glfw-ocaml and lablgl libraries. The program only shows a black window and I didn't manage to draw something in.

I've tried to use shader and the result is the same. I succeed to draw a simple triangle with GLUT. But how to do it with GLFW?

Here's my code (without shader):

```ml
let of_float_array_static arr ~kind =
  let raw = Raw.create_static kind ~len:(Array.length arr) in
  Raw.sets_float raw ~pos:0 arr;
  raw


let () =
  (* Initialize the library *)
  GLFW.init ();
  GLFW.windowHint ~hint:Samples ~value:(Some 4);
  GLFW.windowHint ~hint:ContextVersionMajor ~value:3;
  GLFW.windowHint ~hint:ContextVersionMinor ~value:3;
  GLFW.windowHint ~hint:OpenGLForwardCompat ~value:true;
  GLFW.windowHint ~hint:OpenGLProfile ~value:CoreProfile;

  (* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context *)
  let window = GLFW.createWindow ~width:1024 ~height:768 ~title:"Triangle" () in
  (* Make the window's context current *)
  GLFW.makeContextCurrent ~window:(Some window);

  (* Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below *)
  GLFW.setInputMode ~window:window ~mode:StickyKeys ~value:true;

  (* Dark blue background *)
  GlClear.color (0., 0., 0.4);


  let raw = of_float_array_static [|-1.; -1.; 0.; 1.; -1.; 0.; 0.; 1.; 0.|] ~kind:`float in
  GlArray.vertex `three raw;

  while (not ((GLFW.getKey ~window:window ~key:Escape) || (GLFW.windowShouldClose ~window:window))) do
    (* Render here *)

    (* Clear the screen *)
    GlClear.clear [`color; `depth];

    (* Draw triangle... *)
    GlArray.enable `vertex;
    GlArray.draw_arrays `triangles ~first:0 ~count:3;
    GlArray.disable `vertex;

    (* Swap front and back buffers *)
    GLFW.swapBuffers ~window:window;
    (* Poll for and process events *)
    GLFW.pollEvents ()
  done;

  GLFW.terminate ()
```

I suppose I didn't succeed to draw in the right buffer, but I didn't find any function allowing to draw in a specific buffer. Moreover, the program (except the shaders) works when I use glut.

Comment: Do you see any warnings, when you compile this code?

Comment: With *Core Profile* you need VAO and VBO. Read some modern OGL tutorial. Translating the gl commands to `lablGL` should be straightforward.

Comment: Lablgl is essentially limited to OpenGl 1. However, you are requesting an OpenGL 3 Core Profile which disable compatibility features, like the support for immediate mode used by lablgl.

Comment: A bit off topic but you might have a look at the ocaml vulkan bindings if you aren't set about using lablgl.